# nginx and redirection from another domain

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

So I have `www.old-domain.com` and we've just transferred to `www.new-domain.com`

`old-domain.com`'s server had an SSL certificate and could handle both `http://www.old-domain.com` and `https://old-domain.com`

`www.new-domain.com` is also capable of SSL, with a certificate installed.

In the DNS records of `old-domain.co`m I've routed all traffic to `new-domain.com`

On the NGINX serving www.new-domain.com I've put this at the top of my "default" settings file:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  server_name old-domain.com www.old-domain.com;

  return 301 https://new-domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

is that enough to redirect the traffic correctly to the new domain whether they use `http://old-domain.com` or `https://old-domain.com`?

The reason I suspect it's **not enough** is because after the DNS records updated I am getting this:

- http://old-domain.com -> WORKS
- https://old-domain.com -> Browser warns of "not secured" and offers to proceed unsecured.

note that:

- http://new-domain.com -> WORKS as NGINX directs to https://new-domain.com
- https://new-domain.com -> WORKS

Obviously I'm missing something.

Comment: Nobody's listening on old-domain.com:443

Comment: And you'll need the certificates for old-domain to be able to read the requests.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille  
so you mean the newdomain server (different from the olddomain server) cannot deal with incoming 443 requests made for the oldsite.com because it's not equipped with an SSL certificate for olddomain.com ?

Comment: Unless the server name is sent unencoded (SNI), it wouldn't even be able to determine that. Certainly not the request URI.

Comment: Can't you let the old system do the redirecting for as long as it's certificate is still valid?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille this is what I ended up doing. The old system, with its valid SSL certificate now redirects the traffic with the request URI to the new system. All's well. Thanks. If you write this as an answer I can credit you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the old system do the redirecting for as long as its certificate is still valid